# Cannot define TextView position in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

When I declare 3 TextViews in RelativeLayout, 'textA', 'textB', and 'textC'. The textC should appear below textB. But when run, the textC displayed in improper position (at the top-left of screen).
I don't know can textC use android:layout_below to textB.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="This is TextA : " />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textA"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textA"
        android:text="this is textB" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textC"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/textB"
        android:text="This is TextC" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I just know the alignBaseline should be avoid for this situation. So use relative position to other element would be the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can also change

```
android:layout_below="@id/textA"
```

to textC

The complete Example would look:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="This is TextA : " />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textA"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textA"
    android:text="this is textB" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textC"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textB"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textA"
    android:text="This is TextC" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make below changes for the `TextView3` :

> ```
>  <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/textC"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textB" 
>     android:layout_below="@+id/textA"
>     android:text="This is TextC" />
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It cannot use vertical alignment to the elements that use alignBaseline to other elements. Then in this case in 'textB' change alignBaseline to be alignTop like in the code.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textA"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/textA"
    android:text="this is textB" />
```

Using this way it will support muti-line for textB.